# How to use vectors and references in nested loops?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a parent-child relationship using Structs and Vectors in Rust. The issue I'm having is that when I create a new parent instance and push it to a vector, its value is moved to that vector.

Attempting to add children after pushing the parent into a vector causes an ownership issue. If the parent push is delayed until after adding children this problem doesn't occur.

The Rust playground linked below is a simple example of what I'm trying to do. In reality, there will be another two levels of the hierarchy (parent -> child -> grandchild -> great grandchild).

I've tried using `Box<Parent>` in an attempt to use references and pushing the boxed parent to a `Vec<Box<Parent>>` but the same problem occurs where the reference would be copied, but `Parent` doesn't implement the Copy trait.

I'd like to have one copy of each Struct instance only.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Parent {
    id: usize,
    children: Vec<Child>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
struct Child {
    id: usize,
    age: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let mut parents: Vec<Parent> = Vec::new();

    for parent_id in 1..4 {
        let mut p = Parent {
            id: parent_id,
            children: Vec::new(),
        };

        // If pushed to the vector here, the Parent value is moved
        // and the modifications to `p` in the child loop below are
        // not seen past the outer loop.
        parents.push(p);

        for child_id in 1..3 {
            let c = Child {
                id: child_id,
                age: child_id + 10,
            };
            p.children.push(c);
        }

        // Moving the push to here works but it doesn't
        // feel right having to do this.
        //parents.push(p);
    }

    println!("{:#?}", parents);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `p`
  --> src/main.rs:34:13
   |
19 |         let mut p = Parent {
   |             ----- move occurs because `p` has type `Parent`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
27 |         parents.push(p);
   |                      - value moved here
...
34 |             p.children.push(c);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=12cfc7cde723b2886e3b50ade9d5e4a9)

Comment: The code must be embedded in the question. External links (e.g. to the playground) are not enough.

Comment: Thank you! I debated copying it here because I thought it was too long. Now I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either push the parent after you're done with it, or you can access it via the `Vec`:

```rust
parents.push(p);

let p = parents.last_mut().unwrap();
for child_id in 1..3 {
    let c = Child {
        id: child_id,
        age: child_id + 10,
    };
    p.children.push(c);
}
```

Comment: So this is by design. I wasn't sure if I could use some sort of reference and avoid having to pull the item back out of the vector.